# How to know why server traffic is used and what is using it? (windows os)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-monitoring, traffic

I have a VPS on which I have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed. My monthly traffic is near 100 Gigabytes per month, and I don't have heavy sites on it (no download center, no movies, just text and image).

However, last time when I logged into the server management panel, I saw that the traffic was heavily consumed (near 80 Gigabytes per almost 10 days), and when I logged into the server, I saw that the network is busy (using Task Manager, Network tab). However, I don't know what is using my server. No virus, because I have MSE installed and running there. I stopped all websites, but still network is sending and receiving data.

How to know what process or application is using my network and traffic?

Note: I'm a .NET developer, not a system admin, and this VPS is for personal usage only. And please, I don't care if Linux is better than Windows or not. Also I couldn't find an answer on this site. Maybe this question is duplicate, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: "No virus, because I have MSE installed" that is *not* a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: In addition to what John said, even if it is virus-free, that doesn't mean it hasn't been hacked or compromised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) and see what address the traffic is going out to.

What do you use the VPS for? Does it host any blogs or content management systems? Are they on the lastest stable releases and does the server install patches and security updates? Check that nothing you run on it has potential security issues (does it have Java installed?)

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks. Is there an application like TCPView, but more professional to draw graphs, and let you filter ports, etc?

Comment: Have a look at the rest of the Windows Sysinternals suite - maybe there is but nothing that I'm aware of - TCPView is "good enough" for my needs.

Comment: As a thought, Wireshark might do what you want in regards to filtering, although it's a bit more of a learning curve than TCPView's "double-click and watch" and I don't know about graphs.

Comment: update: if you want something really easy you cant try https://www.glasswire.com/